# Proof inequality using maximum of function

Tags: calculus, inequality

The exercise goes like this:

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{(1+x)^p}{1+x^p}$ for some $p>1$.

Determine its maximum value and use it to prove that for every $a,b>0$, $(a+b)^n<2^{p-1}(a^n+b^n)$.

I have found that $f$ attains its maximum at $x=1$, and $f(1)=2^{p-1}$.

However, I am not able to prove that inequality.

Any hints?

Comment: What is $n$ here? Any restrictions on it, or relation to $p$?

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you want to show is actually
$$(a+b)^n \leq 2^{n-1}(a^n+b^n)$$
(instead of $2^{p-1}$). As a hint, try setting $p=n$ and $x=b/a$ and using the fact that
$$\frac{(1+x)^n}{1+x^n} \leq 2^{n-1}$$